# Producing two functions from a rotated parabola that graph the parabola in question

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-geometry

The following is my attempt at splitting a rotated parabola into two real functions of one real variable (the $x$-coordinate). Let $P$ be the parabola, $V = (x_V, y_V)$ the vertex of $P$, $\alpha$ the angle between the $x$-axis and the line perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of $P$ and growing in counter-clockwise direction. Finally, let $g(t) = \beta t^2$ define the "geometry" of $P$.

[image]

Now, the line perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of $P$ and passing through $V$ (call it $\ell$) is given by equation

$$
y = (x - x_V) \tan \alpha + y_V.
$$

Let $x$ be given. We wish to calculate two values $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $(x, y_1)$ and $(x, y_2)$ are located at the parabola's "lower" and "upper" parts. To do that, I start from $(x, 0)$, go up or down until I reach $\ell$ at point $B$, travel through the line segment $BT$, and finally travel through $TF$. If we fix $V$, $T$ becomes

$$
T(t) = (x_V + t \cos \alpha - \beta t^2 \sin \alpha, y_V + t \sin \alpha + \beta t^2 \cos \alpha).
$$

Next, we set $x = x_V + t \cos\alpha - \beta t^2 \sin \alpha$ and solve for $t$
$$
-\beta \sin(\alpha)t^2 + \cos(\alpha)t + (x_V - x) = 0,
$$

which has solutions
$$
\begin{aligned}
t &= \frac{-\cos\alpha \pm \sqrt{\cos^2\alpha - 4(-\beta\sin\alpha)(x_V - x)}}{-2\beta\sin\alpha} \\
  &= \frac{\cos\alpha \pm \sqrt{\cos^2\alpha + 4\beta\sin\alpha(x_V - x)}}{2\beta\sin\alpha}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, we need to find out $|VB|$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|VB| &= \sqrt{(x - x_V)^2 + (\tan(\alpha)x - \tan(\alpha)x_V + y_V - y_V)^2} \\
     &= \sqrt{(x - x_V)^2 + (\tan(\alpha)x - \tan(\alpha)x_V)^2} \\
     &= \sqrt{(x - x_V)^2 + \tan^2(\alpha)(x - x_V)^2} \\
     &= \sqrt{(x - x_V)^2 (1 + \tan^2(\alpha))^2} \\
     &= (x - x_V)\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally, the desired $y_1$ or $y_2$ are given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
y &= y_S + \sqrt{(|VB| - t)^2 + (\beta t^2)^2} \\
  &= y_S + \sqrt{(|VB| - t)^2 + \beta^2 t^4},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $y_S = \tan(\alpha)(x - x_V) + y_V$.

Question: is this calculation correct? Does it work for all $\alpha$, $\beta$, $V$? (Except $\alpha = n\pi$.)

Comment: It would be a good check on your calculations to plug in some simple values and see if their evaluation comes out sensibly.

Comment: @hardmath Have a program (https://github.com/coderodde/ParabolaDrawer) for that. Unfortunately, something breaks when $\beta > 0$ **and** the parabola is oriented downwards (which is up to the value of $\alpha$), so I had no other options but asking here.

Comment: I'm having difficulty seeing how the ultimate expressions for $y$ answer the problem of breaking the rotated parabola into two curves, each of which is a function of $x$.  It seems to me you've left a dependence on $t$ in the formulas that prevents them from defining two functions of $x$.

Comment: @hardmath Most often $t$ would have two solutions, one producing the point on the upper part and another one on the lower part. Also, the discriminant may become negative, which has no real solution, so that would seem as the mechanism that for some $x$ there is no such $y$.

Comment: Yes, there may be some $x$ for which "there is no such $y$", so breaking the parabola into two curves, both functions of $x$ will involve identifying an interval of $x$ values over which both curves are defined.

Comment: The derivation hits a snag for $\alpha=n\pi$: dividing by zero is invalid.

Comment: @amd I consider it a non-interesting case.

Comment: Maybe relevant : [Understand 1D FEM solution using quadratics elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548856/understand-1d-fem-solution-using-quadratics-elements) ,

Comment: Maybe relevant : [What is wrong with this method for a rotated and shifted parabola?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711004/what-is-wrong-with-this-method-for-a-rotated-and-shifted-parabola)
, [Proving that for each two parabolas, there exists a transformation taking one to the other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667467/proving-that-for-each-two-parabolas-there-exists-a-transformation-taking-one-to)

Comment: @HandeBruijn Maybe relevant, but definitely above my level.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Wait, this is an off-topic question, but do you have anything to do with de Bruijn graphs?

Comment: @coderodde: [N.G. de Bruijn](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaas_Govert_de_Bruijn) has been a professor of mine at the [Eindhoven University of Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eindhoven_University_of_Technology)
at the time I was a student. But he is not a relative or family; neither is [Inge de Bruijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inge_de_Bruijn), for example. De Bruijn (and its variations such as "de Bruyn" and "de Bruin") is quite a common last name in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of the solution will depend on the form in which you put the parabola. Any parabola (or circle or ellipse or hyperbola) in the plane can be expressed in the form $By^2 + Ax^2 + Cx + Dy + Exy + F = 0$. In the case of parabolas of interest here, that do not open up or down, $B$ will not be zero, so without loss of generality we can divide out by $B$ and assume the parabola is of the form $y^2 + Ax^2 + Cx + Dy + Exy + F = 0$. The problem is relatively easy to solve in this form. First, separate all terms with a $y$:

$y^2 + (Ex + D)y = -Ax^2 - Cx - F.$

Then complete the square in $y$ on the LHS:

$y^2 + (Ex + D)y + (\frac{Ex+D}{2})^2 = (\frac{E^2}{4} -A)x^2 + (\frac{ED}{2} - C)x + (\frac{D^2}{4} - F)$

That is,

$(y + \frac{Ex+D}{2})^2 = (\frac{E^2}{4} -A)x^2 + (\frac{ED}{2} - C)x + (\frac{D^2}{4} - F)$

so that

$ y + \frac{Ex+D}{2} = \pm\sqrt{(\frac{E^2}{4} -A)x^2 + (\frac{ED}{2} - C)x + (\frac{D^2}{4} - F)}$

or

$ y = -\frac{Ex+D}{2} \pm\sqrt{(\frac{E^2}{4} -A)x^2 + (\frac{ED}{2} - C)x + (\frac{D^2}{4} - F)}$

with the "upper" curve for $y$ being given by the choice of + in the $\pm$ and the lower by -. (Aside: and there is no solution when the expression inside the square root is negative. If $E^2 < 4A$, that clearly happens whenever $x$ is sufficiently negative or sufficiently positive. On the other hand, we know a rotated parabola either "opens to the right" or "opens to the left", so there will at least be two solutions for all sufficiently positive or all sufficiently negative $x$. Hence, we conclude that if the original curve was a parabola, then in fact $E^2 \geq 4A$.)

Anyhow, to use this solution in your case, I suggest you convert your parabola into this form. In particular, you can start with the upward-opening parabola with vertex $(a, b)$ which has equation $u - b = \beta(v-a)^2$ and then simply rotate about the origin by an angle $\alpha$, e.g. by substituting $u = x\cos\alpha - y\sin\alpha$ and $v = x\sin\alpha + y\cos\alpha$. You can arrange that the rotated vertex ends up at $(x_V, y_V)$ by taking $a = x_V\cos\alpha - y_V\sin\alpha$ and $b = x_V\sin\alpha + y_V\cos\alpha$.

I recognize that this is not a direct answer to the question of whether the expressions you list are correct, but I hope it will still be helpful, given that the original question of what are the expressions for the "upper and lower branches" of the rotated parabola is much simpler starting from the general quadratic equation in the plane as expressed in this solution.

Comment: I can't quite follow your text, neither I want to waste my 50 karma points, so the bounty is yours.

Comment: Well, I certainly would like to help. Would you like to suggest a specific example parabola that I could work out in the above fashion? Would that help? The main point is that if you just work from a general algebraic form of a parabola in the plane, then no trigonometry arises in generating the two functions you want. So the trigonometry can be left entirely to putting the parabola into that standard form. Let me know if a worked example would help, and if so what example, or if there's any other question I can answer about what I wrote.